# How to initialize some tests and not others?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

Using `TestInitialize()`, I can initialize all the tests in the `TestClass`. But if I want only some tests to be initialize and not others, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Move the non-shared initialization of test data to each `[TestMethod]` method.

The initialization method is called once for each test, so simply move code you dont want run for all tests into the specific methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by separating them into two classes. Or, if they both use the same methods and variables, put them into subclasses that inherit from a common base class with shared methods and data.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to separate your `Test Methods` into different `Test Classes`. However If you want to have them all in one `Test Class` you can create different initialization methods for each test:

```
[TestClass]
public class TestClass
{
    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        switch (TestContext.TestName)
        {
            case "TestMethod1":
                this.InitializeTestMethod1();
                break;

            case "TestMethod2":
                this.InitializeTestMethod2();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod2()
    {
    }

    private void InitializeTestMethod1()
    {
        // Initialize TestMethod1
    }

    private void InitializeTestMethod2()
    {
        // Initialize TestMethod2
    }

    public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }
}
```